# How to handle a exception in a SQL function?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, exception, plsql

I wanted to make a function that returns the maximum value between 3 different numbers.

In case that two of these 3 numbers had the same value, it had to return an exception.

My code returns the maximum value if the 3 numbers are different, but when two of them are the same, it returns error. What's wrong? Any help? Thank you in advance!!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NUMEROMAYOR1(num1 NUMBER, num2 NUMBER, num3 NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
numeromayor NUMBER;
igualdad EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
IF (num1=num2) OR (num1=num3) OR (num2=num3) THEN
   RAISE igualdad;
   END IF;
   IF (num1>num2) AND (num1>num3) THEN
   numeromayor:=num1;
   ELSIF (num3>num2) AND (num3>num1) THEN
   numeromayor:=num3;
   ELSIF (num2>num1) AND (num2>num3) THEN
   numeromayor:=num2;
   END IF;
   RETURN(numeromayor);
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN igualdad THEN
   dbms_output.put_line('Numbers can't be repeated');
   END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because

- `OR` should be `AND`,
- function doesn't return a value in case of an error
- you have to use two consecutive single quotes

---

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NUMEROMAYOR1 (num1  NUMBER,
  2                                           num2  NUMBER,
  3                                           num3  NUMBER)
  4     RETURN NUMBER
  5  IS
  6     numeromayor  NUMBER;
  7     igualdad     EXCEPTION;
  8  BEGIN
  9     IF     (num1 = num2)
 10        AND (num1 = num3)     --> was OR
 11        AND (num2 = num3)     --> was OR
 12     THEN
 13        RAISE igualdad;
 14     END IF;
 15
 16     IF     (num1 > num2)
 17        AND (num1 > num3)
 18     THEN
 19        numeromayor := num1;
 20     ELSIF     (num3 > num2)
 21           AND (num3 > num1)
 22     THEN
 23        numeromayor := num3;
 24     ELSIF     (num2 > num1)
 25           AND (num2 > num3)
 26     THEN
 27        numeromayor := num2;
 28     END IF;
 29
 30     RETURN (numeromayor);
 31  EXCEPTION
 32     WHEN igualdad
 33     THEN
 34        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Numbers can''t  be   repeated');   --> consecutive ''
 35        RETURN NULL;                                              --> was missing
 36  END;
 37  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT numeromayor1 (1, 1, 1) FROM DUAL;

NUMEROMAYOR1(1,1,1)
-------------------


Numbers can't  be   repeated
SQL> SELECT numeromayor1 (1, 2, 3) FROM DUAL;

NUMEROMAYOR1(1,2,3)
-------------------
                  3

SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry, the ' stuff is because I translated it to english here, but that's not the issue.

About the "AND" I think that should be "OR" because the error should be thrown in case just two of the values were the same. Not all of them.

Comment: OK. What's the problem, then? Which values do you pass to the function, what result do you expect, and which return that "error" you're talking about?

Comment: I think it's just a reimplementation of the existing SQL `greatest()` function.

Comment: Not exactly, @William, as the OP wants to return an "error" if two values are the same.

Answer (score 0):

A function has to either return something or else raise an exception. Also, all the brackets and individual `if` tests (not to mention the layout and the uppercase code) make it hard to follow the logic. A slightly cleaned up version would be:

```
create or replace function numeromayor1
    ( num1 number
    , num2 number
    , num3 number )
    return number
as
    numeromayor number;
    igualdad    exception;
begin
    if num1 in (num2, num3) or num2 = num3 then
        raise igualdad;
    end if;

    if num1 = greatest(num1, num2, num3) then
        numeromayor := num1;
    elsif num3 = greatest(num1, num2, num3) then
        numeromayor := num3;
    elsif num2 = greatest(num1, num2, num3) then
        numeromayor := num2;
    end if;

    return numeromayor;
exception
    when igualdad then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Numbers can''t be repeated');
end numeromayor1;
```

But personally I would simplify it:

```
create or replace function numeromayor1
    ( num1 number
    , num2 number
    , num3 number )
    return number
as
begin
    if num1 in (num2, num3) or num2 = num3 then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Numbers can''t be repeated');
    end if;

    return greatest(num1, num2, num3);
end numeromayor1;
```

The uniqueness check could also be written in a more extendable style:

```
create or replace function numeromayor1
    ( num1 number
    , num2 number
    , num3 number )
    return number
is
    type ntt is table of number;
begin
    if ntt(num1, num2, num3) is not a set then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Los números no se pueden repetir');
    end if;

    return greatest(num1, num2, num3);
end numeromayor1;
```